# How to run node.js code on the server automatically?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am using a node package([sitemap-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap-generator)) to create a sitemap.xml file for my angular website,
At the moment I am running this code manually on my machine then uploading the generated file each time.
Is there any way I can automate this process, maybe by uploading the code and running it periodically and automatically

Comment: If you're on a unix or unix-like server (Linux, Mac, WSL) you can just create a cron job

Answer (score 0):

You can use `node-scehdule`  module to run sitemap generator everyday at a specific time , you can set time according to your requirement

```
   const SitemapGenerator = require('sitemap-generator');
    const cron = require('node-schedule');
    const generator = SitemapGenerator('https://examaple.com', {
        maxDepth: 0,
        filepath: '/var/www/example.com/sitemap.xml',
        maxEntriesPerFile: 50000,
        stripQuerystring: true,
        lastMod:true
    });
    cron.schedule('0 22 * * *', () => {
        console.log("will run at 10:00 PM everyday");
        generator.start();
    });
```